# When trying to load a clob to an Oracle table, loading too many records

Tags: xml, oracle, clob, sql-loader

I have an .xml file that I am trying to load into a clob field in an Oracle table. The .xml file is 49 lines in length. When I run my sqlloader cntl, the entire .xml file gets loaded into my table as a new row, 49 times. I am using Oracle 11.2.0.3   What am I doing wrong?

```
CREATE TABLE "LEAD_REPORTING_CLOB" 
("SHARED_XML" CLOB);
```

my cntl:

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE * 
REPLACE

INTO TABLE LEAD_REPORTING_CLOB
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
SHARED_XML        LOBFILE(CONSTANT '/export/RFD/Lead_Reports/LEADRPT.xml') TERMINATED BY EOF
)


xml file:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LeadReport xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.xxx.yyy/efile">
  <Lead>
    <SubmissionId>530153999999zdhxxx</SubmissionId>
    <PatternDescription>OLF</PatternDescription>
    <SourceIPAddress>
      <IPAddress>
        <IPv4AddressTxt>999.99.99.999</IPv4AddressTxt>
      </IPAddress>
      <TCPPortNumber>443</TCPPortNumber>
      <IPTs>2016-02-05T13:16:55-05:00</IPTs>
    </SourceIPAddress>
    <SourceDeviceId>
      <DeviceId>74B3A80AE5C99X9X99999C17XX59E5XX3779999A</DeviceId>
      <DeviceIdTs>2016-02-05T13:16:55-05:00</DeviceIdTs>
    </SourceDeviceId>
    <AdditionalInformation>
      <ReturnSubmStatus>A</ReturnSubmStatus>
     <EFIN>555555</EFIN>
      <EmailAddressDomain>GMAIL.COM</EmailAddressDomain>
      <PhoneNumberLastFour>1899</PhoneNumberLastFour>
    </AdditionalInformation>
  </Lead>
  <Lead>
    <SubmissionId>9999992016108floxxx2</SubmissionId>
    <AssociatedState>
      <StateSubmissionId>9999992016108xhaxxx2</StateSubmissionId>
      <StateOrCityCode>GAST</StateOrCityCode>
    </AssociatedState>
    <PatternDescription>OLF</PatternDescription>
    <SourceIPAddress>
      <IPAddress>
        <IPv4AddressTxt>188.88.8.188</IPv4AddressTxt>
      </IPAddress>
      <TCPPortNumber>443</TCPPortNumber>
      <IPTs>2016-04-17T08:07:54-04:00</IPTs>
    </SourceIPAddress>
    <SourceDeviceId>
      <DeviceId>6B9D4C4B0159XXX8FA30391BC8A099999009B366</DeviceId>
      <DeviceIdTs>2016-04-17T08:07:54-04:00</DeviceIdTs>
    </SourceDeviceId>
    <AdditionalInformation>
      <ReturnSubmStatus>A</ReturnSubmStatus>
      <EFIN>444444</EFIN>
      <EmailAddressDomain>YAHOO.COM</EmailAddressDomain>
      <PhoneNumberLastFour>3822</PhoneNumberLastFour>
    </AdditionalInformation>
  </Lead>
</LeadReport>
```

Answer (score 0):

The typical setup for Oracle Loader with LOBs would be:

- The control file with the loading instructions
- There is a main datafile with the meta data (author, date, filename). Each line in the file becomes a row in the target table.
- There is a separate file for each entry in the main file, which is loaded into the CLOB or BLOB column of the target table.

In your case, the XML files seems to be used as both the main data file and the separate LOB file (though I don't fully understand why; are you also specifying the XML on the command line?).

So you need to specify these three things properly. In order to avoid three files, you put the main data file into the control file using the BEGINDATA directive (this is what the astrisk after INFILE is for):

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE * 
REPLACE

INTO TABLE LEAD_REPORTING_CLOB
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
    FILENAME,
    SHARED_XML  LOBFILE(FILENAME) TERMINATED BY EOF
)

BEGINDATA
/export/RFD/Lead_Reports/LEADRPT.xml
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, Codo. This is so new to me and I really want to understand it. I have just the one input .xml file. Are you thinking I should have an additional file to go along with it? It doesn't sound like I need it. My command line contains the .xml file name as 'data='. Is there a way to avoid having the name in both places? I tried the cntl file you provided but got an error.  Expecting keyword INTO, found "(".
(
^

Comment: That explains my open question. As you specify it on the command line, the XML file is used both as the main data file as well as the LOB file to load. Don't specify it on the command line. It's in conflict with the INFILE clause. As for the error, I'll investigate it.

Comment: I've updated the control file commands. Hopefully, it works now.

Comment: Thanks Codo! That worked. I do have one more question though. I have managed to write a sql that will extract the individual fields from the clob. It works fine when there is just one occurrence or record within the clob. If there are multiple, as in the one I presented above, then I get an error EXTRACTVALUE returns value of only one node.  Is my only option to use XMLTABLE? Do I need an XML schema available to do that? I am not sure I have access to one. Like I said, I'm really new to this .xml/clob stuff, so if what I am asking doesn't make sense, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad it work. As for your follow-up question, I don't really understand it (what is an *occurrence* or *record*? what does your current query look like?). You're better off starting a new question focusing on extracting data from the CLOB.

Comment: I'm sorry for confusing you. There would actually be multiple records in the clob when extracting the data. There would be multiple sets of submission ids, state submission ids, etc. Everything that falls between the <Lead> and </Lead> tags would be a new table entry when I parse the data. Here is a sample of my code:

Comment: Start a new question.

Comment: select      
              nvl(EXTRACTVALUE(xmltype(ocr.shared_xml),
                        '//Lead/SubmissionId',
                        'xmlns="http://www.xxx.yyy/efile"'),
           '') as "SubmissionId",
              nvl(EXTRACTVALUE(xmltype(ocr.shared_xml),
                        '//Lead//StateSubmissionId',
                        'xmlns="http://www.xxx.yyy/efile"'),
           '') as "state_submission_id"
                
    FROM 
       lead_reporting_clob ocr;

Comment: That looks like a mess. I will start a new question. Thanks you for all of your help!